# How to flush varnishlog buffer to output?

Tags: varnish

I have a varnishlog process running in background like this:

```
nohup varnishlog -c -m TxStatus:503 >/root/varnishlog.txt &
```

But because of buffering, I cannot fully see last request and response until new error occur. Is there a way to flush current buffer to output? Killing varnishlog process doesn't help, I just loose last logged request. Maybe there's a better way to log 503 errors returned by Varnish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add -u to unbuffer the output.

```
nohup varnishlog -u -c -m TxStatus:503 >/root/varnishlog.txt &
```

reference: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishlog.html